# Accessing the TwiML parameters using a GET/POST request

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to request parameters form the TwiML Voice Requests. I'm especially interested in in the gather verb that will allow me to figure out how many users "Pressed" a specific Digit.

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters
http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action

I've seen most of the code is in xml but was wondering if there was a python equivalent code of the above.

Answer (score 0):

The Gather verb is created in XML but you can use a static template such as the one here:
http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/weatherbyphone#step2

The key things are specifying how many digits you expect and what the next step (action) is.

Then after the user pressed the digit, you can process the results with Python too. Here's an example from our Howtos:
http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/weatherbyphone#step3

Does that make sense?